# Can I tell if I queried a field?

Tags: apex, soql, sobject, schema

I have some code that queries some fields from an object.  I then use the schema to loop over all of the fields of an object.  Is there a way, while I'm looping through the schema to tell if I had queried for a field before I try to use the sobject.get method?

```
List<Account> accs = [SELECT RecordTypeId, Name FROM Account];

List<Schema.SObjectField> fields = Schema.SOBjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values();
for (Account acc: accs)
{
  for (Schema.SObjectField field: fields)
  {
    //This will fail if I did not query for the field
    Object sField = acc.get(field.getDescribe().getName());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just came up with an idea:

```
try
{
  Object sfield = audit.get(fromName);
} catch (Exception e)
{
  continue;
}
```

Does anyone have a better idea without catching it if there is an error though?

Comment: This is generally very bad practice to use a try catch as a part of regular code flow.

Answer (score 9):

Use `Map<String, Object> getPopulatedFieldsAsMap()` method on the sobject. It gives you a map of fields and values that got queried.

Please refer to this release notes for more information: (http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_apex_sobject_getmap.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately, this method won't include ALL fields that were in the SOQL query - it will only return fields with non-null values

Answer (score 1):

the only other way to do this besides a `try`/`catch` is to write your **query dynamically** so that you get every field.

Example:

```
string queryString = 'SELECT ';
for(string field:Schema.SOBjectType.Account.fields.getMap().values())
    queryString += field+',';
queryString = queryString.removeEnd(',') + ' FROM Account';

if(stillNeedsToAddToQuery) // add WHERE, LIMIT, etc. stuff if need be
    // stuff

list<Account> accountList = (list<Account>)database.query(queryString); 
// database.query() returns  list<sObject>, so I like to cast my result
```

See my answer here for some `Utility Methods` + `Test Code`:   [Can a SOQL query selecting all columns be generated at runtime?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25454/can-a-soql-query-selecting-all-columns-be-generated-at-runtime/25456#25456)

---

*Update*

Both @dphil and my answers are equivalent but opposite in a sense when you are dealing with "general" query results:

- You either filter the input fields for the query (*My method  gives you all of the fields, and then you can create another method to filter for the appropriate situation.*)
- `try`/`catch` whatever the "general" query result is. (*And there are clever things that can be done in the `catch` part too such as break the loop, write another query adding the  missing field, and  try again with the re-queried results.*)

Comment: My problem is that I don't want every field.  I only want the fields I specifically query for for a reason.

Comment: then yea, "try"/"catch" is the only way to go.  you can get creative with either your method or my method to get elegant results.

Comment: check out my update :)

Comment: The thing is that your answer actually does the opposite of what I need.  I did not give the entire picture, only a piece that shows a similar case of **how** it is being used.  It doesn't explain the **why** because it is not important for the answer.  The answers actually aren't equivalent because of the bigger picture that I did not give you.

Comment: I already have the query, and so building it dynamically doesn't help me any.  The answers actually aren't equivalent because the end result is very different.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to convert the sobject to JSON and use the parser.

```
Contact myContact = [SeLect Id, Name FROM Contact LIMIT 1];
String contactJson = JSON.serialize(myContact);
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(contactJson);

Set<String> queriedFields = new Set<String>();

JSONToken token = parser.nextToken();
token = parser.nextToken(); 
while(parser.hasCurrentToken() ){
  String text = parser.getText();
  if(JSONToken.START_OBJECT == token){
    parser.skipChildren();
    token = parser.nextToken();
  }
  if('attributes' != text && JSONToken.FIELD_NAME == token)
      queriedFields.add(parser.getText());

   token = parser.nextToken();
}

for(String field : queriedFields){
    System.debug(field);
}
```