# Adding Date criterion in WHERE Clause

Tags: apex, soql

Here I am doing an aggregate SOQL

```
List<AggregateResult> ListName = [select SUM(Field1__c), SUM(Field2__c), 
                      from CustomObject__c  
                      where Object2__r.Id In :List2 
                      AND ( createdDate>=: StartDateQuarter 
                      AND createdDate<=: EndDateQuarter ) 
                      GROUP BY Object2__r.Name, Object2__r.Id ];
```

This is where I am determining the dates.

```
List<Period> LastDates = [Select type, StartDate, EndDate From Period WHERE type = 'Quarter' AND StartDate = LAST_N_QUARTERS:4 LIMIT 1];
Datetime StartDateQuarterLast = LastDates[0].StartDate;
Datetime EndDateQuarterLast = LastDates[0].EndDate;
```

This query is working when I am removing the DATE part.
NOT working with the DATE filter.

StartDateQuarter and EndDateQuarter  are getting values. I have checked that.

Is there any syntactical error?

Answer (score 2):

I can find no reference in the SOQL documentation to `StartDateQuarter` or `EndDateQuarter`. If those are custom fields, the may need to be appended with `__c` and you'd need to remove the colons that precede them.

Otherwise, based on the [SOQL Documentation for DateFormats](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm), I believe the date part of your query needs to be revised to use one or more of the following to specify the quarter:

THIS_QUARTER, LAST_QUARTER, NEXT_QUARTER, NEXT_N_QUARTERS:n, LAST_N_QUARTERS:n, THIS_FISCAL_QUARTER, LAST_FISCAL_QUARTER, NEXT_FISCAL_QUARTER, NEXT_N_FISCAL_​QUARTERS:n, or LAST_N_FISCAL_​QUARTERS:n.

To do this, you may need to run 2 queries, one to determine the "relative" quarter in which the created date falls in and then your final query.

Comment: I found out the issue to be Date format mismatch. My debug log is showing StartDateQuarter/EndDateQuarter  as YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss and the created date format has YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ssZ . S o the Z at the end seems to be the cause . Any idea how I can correct that quickly?

Comment: @SFDCRookie try using convertTimezone(CreatedDate) in place of createdDate. Hope it may help you.

Comment: One is a Date and the other is a Date-Time value. You need the Date(CreatedDate) equivalent in SOQL which I think is [FORMAT ()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_format.htm?search_text=date).

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy Unless the date is used in his groupby, that wouldn't be of any use to him, so I don't think that's what he's looking for. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_convert_time_zone.htm?search_text=converttimezone.

Comment: @SaumyaRanjanSatapathy - I am getting a "Invalid aggregate function: convertTimezone"  in Dev console- Not sure why

Comment: @SFDCRookie I belive your query is not working because you are comparing date in two different time zone. Try to convert both to a single time zone, may be by using Datetime.valueOf() or Datetime.valueOfGmt().

Comment: @SFDCRookie Are you getting query syntax error or just the result of the query is blan? I hope you are getting the second one.

Comment: @SFDCRookie  I don't think selecting a TimeZone is the solution to your problem. Try using FORMAT(). If you do try a TimeZone, simply use GMT as the TZ is irrelevant, thus the reason you want to use Format to convert to Date.

Comment: @crmprogdev -I assumed the Z criterion because it worked with .CreatedDate > 2011-01-01T00:00:00Z and o.CreatedDate < 2011-12-31T00:00:00Z  - So you mean I should use GMT for both ?Where should I use the FORMAT ? It will not allow me to use in the WHERE clause

Comment: Try using DATE(CreatedDate). FORMAT() in apex would convert that to a string. In apex, DATE() would convert a date-time to a date. SOQL should see the same behavior.

Comment: But Format can only be used in Select query . It is not allowed in the WHERE clause or any other place.

Comment: If DATE() doesn't work for you (FORMAT is not what you need), you may have hit a wall if you want to see results by quarter unless you run this as two queries to first get a map of `Quarter` to `CreatedDate`.

Comment: [this is what I found](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25441/how-is-a-datetime-object-formatted-into-a-string-suitable-for-a-string-based-soq): `String formattedDt = dt.format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss\'Z\'');` should dod the trick, or you can even try `formatGmt(dateFormatString)` from [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_formatGmt)

Comment: @Oleksiy The issue is that he needs to use the CreatedDate QUERY FIELD in his WHERE clause as a DATE FIELD (not a value), so he doesn't need to format an actual string. Instead, he needs the SOQL engine to convert the Date-time field to read it as a DATE field when constructing & running the query. He's not passing the data into the query. It's collecting it as part of the query.

Comment: @SFDCRookie The only error I get when try to format CreatedDate criteria is `value of filter criterion for field 'CreatedDate' must be of type dateTime and should not be enclosed in quotes`, so `DateTime.newInstanceGMT(LastDates[0].StartDate, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0));` should work

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to make sure you get the correct `Period` record by sorting them newest first.

```
List<Period> recentQuarters = [
    SELECT StartDate, EndDate
    FROM Period
    WHERE Type = 'Quarter'
    ORDER BY StartDate DESC
    LIMIT 1
];
```